# Does the execution of a PHP script halts when the connection wih the user is slow?

Tags: php

Lets imagine a situation like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
someFunction();
?>

<html>
<head>The headers...</head>
<body>Loooooots of content</body>
</html>

<?
executeSomething();
?>
```

If the connection with the client is slow and the `HTML` part is big, so it takes a long time to transfer, will the second PHP block `executeSomething();` hang until the `HTML` is completely transmitted?

Comment: it depends on buffer output, but php execution is less than page loading, then, your function will be executed surely.

Answer (score 1):

No. The PHP processor will execute all php-parts of the HTML file and only after he has finished will start sending the user the complete HTML data.

But you can, if you want, send some HTML data already while the PHP processor is still processing PHP with [ob_flush()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php). Then your script will run until [the time limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) is reached.

To use `ob_flush()` you have to initialize it first: [ob_start()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php). Then you can send the buffered data to the user with the desired `ob_`-function.